# Java Vs python AES PBKDF2. Why different output?

Tags: java, python, encryption, aes, pbkdf2

I am trying to write a java program for the following python code.
Please see followings code for both the programs.
My problem is both of these programs are producing different output for
same encryption key and same input value. Please help me what I have done wrong?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. In Python you generate the iv as output of pbkdf2, in java  you set iv=salt. Just a quick shot as I'm on my phone

Comment: Hey thanks Michael for the welcome. I am just a newbie to the world of python/java. I don't know how to extract IV from generated 'secretKeyfinal' in the above java program as it is done in the python program 'aes_iv = generator.read(16)' . Can you tell me how to get IV to pass in cipher.init() function.

Comment: Actually I want to write  the java program producing same output as the above python program where I have predefined encryption key = '58xZ4dP3K762WtpDVt5EjqnNdfTZD844s8CAW5gGy9w7WMhuVtUPJ7xU2EMCrFQk'  and salt = {83, 71, 26, 58, 54, 35, 22, 11, 83, 71, 26, 58, 54, 35, 22, 11};

Comment: it seems your switched some data. key is the encrypted Data and mkj... is the input for pbkdf2. As I'm Not python specialist I cannot find the Java code, sorry. Just for others -what is the expected decrypted text?

Comment: Please don not worry about the python code I just want to write a java program which takes Encryption key ="58xZ4dP3K762WtpDVt5EjqnNdfTZD844s8CAW5gGy9w7WMhuVtUPJ7xU2EMCrFQk" ..............SALT = {83, 71, 26, 58, 54, 35, 22, 11, 83, 71, 26, 58, 54, 35, 22, 11} .....and .....Input = mkjhytfd48j  ..........and produces output= XB+RbZ6RIymFbWFmjoTf5w==

Comment: I'm sorry but without knowledge of all details of the  (python) encryption method you will never been able to write a successful method in Java. The PBKDF2 method usually takes a 3rd param iterations and a 4th param hashmethod, both of them are missing. So finding a decryption method is like searching a needle in a stack of hay.

Comment: I find the following differences / bugs in the Java code: 1. Don't Base64 decode the password (`secretKey`), 2. don't generate the IV from the salt, but via PBKDF2 (see 1. comment of Michael Fehr), 3. extend the keysize generated by PBKDF2 (128 + 256, instead of 256), 4. separate IV and key (in **this** order) from the byte array (`originalKey.getEncoded()`) generated by PBKDF2 and use both for initializing `cipher`. BTW, default iteration count (1000) and digest (SHA1) in the Python code match the parameters used in the Java code.

Comment: Hey Topaco thanks for the guidance. I don't know how to  separate IV and key (in this order) from the byte array (originalKey.getEncoded()) generated by PBKDF2. Can you please help me regarding this.

Comment: Just copy the data of IV and key from `originalKey.getEncoded()` into two new byte arrays for IV and key e.g. with `System.arraycopy`. The first 16 bytes in `originalKey.getEncoded()` are the IV, the following 32 bytes are the key.

Comment: Hey !! Michael and Topaco !! Guys I am very happy and thankful to your nice suggestions. Finally I successfully executed my java program to get the correct output. Thanks again to both of you. I would be posting the final code here after some formatting. Thanks again guys.. :)

Comment: Vikas Dhika: good to read, congrats! @Topaco: is there any programming language or crypto-lib you dont't know or don't know about 'hidden' details like iteration and hash-algo :-). It's good to have you here on SO!