# Java vs Python AES PBKDF2

Tags: python, java, encryption, aes, pbkdf2

I'm attempting to decrypt some values in an Apache Nifi (1.23.1) `flow.xml.gz` (or `flow.json.gz`) file in Python. From doing some patching of the Java files, I've found the following information:

| Field | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Algorithm | `NIFI_PBKDF2_AES_GCM_256` |
| Password | `1+LFssX4whxz9lOPQ9OS7g4NvQzbCe8j` |
| `binary` as described in [CipherPropertyEncryptor.java](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/main/nifi-commons/nifi-property-encryptor/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/encrypt/CipherPropertyEncryptor.java#L63) | `697a84312aac99fbe2315f0637c960352242e26ffd3e2c33c298f06730fffa9687cb0d845f57c1a645` |
| `cipherbinary` as described in [CipherPropertyEncryptor.java](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/main/nifi-commons/nifi-property-encryptor/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/encrypt/CipherPropertyEncryptor.java#L65) | `2242e26ffd3e2c33c298f06730fffa9687cb0d845f57c1a645` |
| [Salt](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/rel/nifi-1.23.1/nifi-commons/nifi-security-utils/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/security/util/crypto/AbstractSecureHasher.java#L34) | `NiFi Static Salt` |
| [Iterations](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/rel/nifi-1.23.1/nifi-commons/nifi-security-crypto-key/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/security/crypto/key/pbkdf2/Pbkdf2DerivedKeyParameterSpecReader.java#L27) | 160,000 |
| Decrypted Value | `Changeit!` |

When trying to write a decryption program in Python, I used https://asecuritysite.com/encryption/aes_gcm2 as a guide.

I have the following code, which results in a `ValueError: MAC check failed`

```py
# https://asecuritysite.com/encryption/aes_gcm2

from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import hashlib
from Crypto.Protocol.KDF import PBKDF2
from Crypto.Hash import SHA256, SHA512

# plaintext='Changeit!'
password='1+LFssX4whxz9lOPQ9OS7g4NvQzbCe8j'
salt = b'NiFi Static Salt'

def decrypt(ciphertext, key, mode):
  (ciphertext, authTag, nonce) = ciphertext
  encobj = AES.new(key,  mode, nonce)
  return(encobj.decrypt_and_verify(ciphertext, authTag))

key = hashlib.sha256(password.encode()).digest()

# /home/nifi/nifi/nifi-commons/nifi-security-crypto-key/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/security/crypto/key/pbkdf2/Pbkdf2DerivedKeyProvider.java says sha512 hmac
# /home/nifi/nifi/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-cipher-bundle/nifi-cipher-processors/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/processors/cipher/DecryptContent.java key length bytes 16
key = PBKDF2(password, salt, 16, count=160000, hmac_hash_module=SHA512)
# key = PBKDF2(password, salt, 32, count=160000, hmac_hash_module=SHA256) # from original code example

# 697a84312aac99fbe2315f0637c960352242e26ffd3e2c33c298f06730fffa9687cb0d845f57c1a645 from a real run, should decrypt to Changeit!
#                                 2242e26ffd3e2c33c298f06730fffa9687cb0d845f57c1a645 cipherbinary from java

# in java, IV in /home/nifi/nifi/nifi-commons/nifi-property-encryptor/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/encrypt/KeyedCipherPropertyEncryptor.java is 697a84312aac99fbe2315f0637c96035   
ciphertext = (b'697a84312aac99fbe2315f0637c96035', b'2242e26ffd3e2c33c2', b'98f06730fffa9687cb0d845f57c1a645')

res = decrypt(ciphertext,key,AES.MODE_GCM)
print ("\n\nDecrypted:\t",res.decode())
```

[Java Vs python AES PBKDF2. Why different output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62967725/22814155) also looks to be relevant, but w/o the original code it's hard to follow what the issues was and how it was resolved.

How can I fix this decryption method to get the correct value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nonce, ciphertext and tag must be hex decoded. In addition, the values for the actual ciphertext, the authentication tag, and the nonce are incorrectly assigned (correct: ciphertext -> 0x2242..., tag -> 0x98f0..., nonce -> 0x697a...). And the key generated with PBKDF2 must be 32 bytes (not 16 bytes).

The following code, which fixes these bugs, decrypts the ciphertext correctly:

```py
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Hash import SHA512
from Crypto.Protocol.KDF import PBKDF2

# plaintext='Changeit!'
password='1+LFssX4whxz9lOPQ9OS7g4NvQzbCe8j'
salt = b'NiFi Static Salt'

def decrypt(ciphertext, key, mode):
  (ciphertext, authTag, nonce) = ciphertext
  encobj = AES.new(key,  mode, nonce)
  return(encobj.decrypt_and_verify(ciphertext, authTag))
  
key = PBKDF2(password, salt, 32, count=160000, hmac_hash_module=SHA512) # 32 bytes key
ciphertext = (
    bytes.fromhex('2242e26ffd3e2c33c2'),                # actual ciphertext 
    bytes.fromhex('98f06730fffa9687cb0d845f57c1a645'),  # authentication tag
    bytes.fromhex('697a84312aac99fbe2315f0637c96035')   # nonce
) 

res = decrypt(ciphertext, key, AES.MODE_GCM)
print ("\n\nDecrypted:\t",res.decode()) # Decrypted:   Changeit!
```