# Python vs ruby AES PBKDF2

Tags: python, ruby, encryption, aes, pbkdf2

I have a working python AES-256-GCM snippet from https://stackoverflow.com/a/77376155/22814155:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Hash import SHA512
from Crypto.Protocol.KDF import PBKDF2

# plaintext='Changeit!'
password='1+LFssX4whxz9lOPQ9OS7g4NvQzbCe8j'
salt = b'NiFi Static Salt'

def decrypt(ciphertext, key, mode):
  (ciphertext, authTag, nonce) = ciphertext
  encobj = AES.new(key,  mode, nonce)
  return(encobj.decrypt_and_verify(ciphertext, authTag))
  
key = PBKDF2(password, salt, 32, count=160000, hmac_hash_module=SHA512) # 32 bytes key
ciphertext = (
    bytes.fromhex('2242e26ffd3e2c33c2'),                # actual ciphertext 
    bytes.fromhex('98f06730fffa9687cb0d845f57c1a645'),  # authentication tag
    bytes.fromhex('697a84312aac99fbe2315f0637c96035')   # nonce
) 

res = decrypt(ciphertext, key, AES.MODE_GCM)
print ("\n\nDecrypted:\t",res.decode()) # Decrypted:   Changeit!
```

However, I'm attempting to translate this to Ruby. I have the following code:

```
require 'openssl'

password = '1+LFssX4whxz9lOPQ9OS7g4NvQzbCe8j'
salt = 'NiFi Static Salt'

def decrypt(ciphertext, auth_tag, key, nonce)
  password = '1+LFssX4whxz9lOPQ9OS7g4NvQzbCe8j'
  salt = 'NiFi Static Salt'.bytes.join('')
  decipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('AES-256-GCM')
  decipher.decrypt
  decipher.key = key
  decipher.iv = nonce
  decipher.auth_tag = auth_tag

  decrypted_text = decipher.update(ciphertext)
  decrypted_text << decipher.final
  decrypted_text
end

key = OpenSSL::PKCS5.pbkdf2_hmac(password, salt, 160000, 32, 'SHA512')
ciphertext = ["2242e26ffd3e2c33c2"].pack('H*')                      # actual ciphertext
auth_tag = ["98f06730fffa9687cb0d845f57c1a645"].pack('H*')        # authentication tag
nonce =   ["697a84312aac99fbe2315f0637c96035"].pack('H*')         # nonce

res = decrypt(ciphertext, auth_tag, key, nonce)

puts "\n\nDecrypted:\t#{res}"
```

However, it errors with `/tmp/test.rb:12:in iv=': iv must be 12 bytes (ArgumentError)`. The nonce is definitely larger than 12 bytes, however it was in python as well. Not sure what the difference is or how to correct it.

Comment: Currently the call `res = decrypt(ciphertext, auth_tag, key, ciphertext[2])` doesn't seem to take the nonce? Please do provide working code! I'm wondering a bit what is happening here. In principle API's can decide to only support the default 12 bytes, but as the wrapper is created on top of the OpenSSL libraries there is really no reason to do that.

Comment: Good call, `ciphertext[2]` was meant to be `nonce`. Simple error when cleaning up the code to post here so it would be more readable.

Comment: Ruby/OpenSSL also supports nonce sizes not equal to 12 bytes. For this, `iv_len` must be set accordingly: `decipher.iv_len = 16`

Comment: @Topaco with the correct answer, again.

Comment: Hmm, weird API design though. OK, I'll remember, in Ruby's OpenSSL lib you should set nonce size and in C# you shouldn't...